# How to add LDAP group for ssh access by ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have LDAP Group.

```
superproduct1
```

In LDAP Group has some users:

```
developer1, tester1, analitic1, project1
```

I want to create ansible playbook for add LDAP group to SSH access on host.

Found only

[group – Add or remove groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_module.html)

```
- name: Ensure group "somegroup" exists
  group:
    name: somegroup
    state: present
```

How to add LDAP group superproduct1 for ssh access?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit /etc/groups since the LDAP group already exists in your LDAP database. You want to let SSH know to use it, try using the AllowGroups setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

From the manpage: "If specified, login is allowed only for users whose primary 
group or supplementary group list matches one of the patterns.  Only group     names are valid; a numerical group ID is not recognized.  By default, login is allowed for all groups."

See [this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638944/ansible-to-update-sshd-config-file)

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @TheFiddlerWins, there is no need to add ldap groups into /etc/group.

The challenge here is to give ssh a way to access your ldap directory:
I did this some time ago by adding a custom script to the sshd config, but using pam looks a lot cleaner today.

Then you just need to handle the required changes using your playbook.

Just remember that your ldap accounts will need a posixAccount object in order to be able to log into you ubuntu boxes.